# TFS 2010: How to create BuildDetail Links that can be displayed in a webbrowser?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, build

```
public class AddHyperlinkToBuildOutput : CodeActivity
{
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<IBuildDetail> BuildDetail { get; set; }

    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> DisplayText { get; set; }

    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> Url { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        var buildDetail = context.GetValue(BuildDetail);
        var displayText = context.GetValue(DisplayText);
        var url = context.GetValue(Url);

        buildDetail.Information.AddExternalLink(displayText, new Uri(url));
        buildDetail.Information.Save();
    }
}
```

With this I can create a link on my Build detail log ([Customize Team Build 2010 – Part 13: Get control over the Build Output](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/10/02/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-13-Get-control-over-the-Build-Output.aspx).

The problem I have that the link is opened in the text editor of Visual Studio 2010.

The link looks like: `file://///ServerName/BuildResult/Tests.html`

How is it possible to open a web browser to show the Tests.html page?

Comment: What is the URL you passed in? What happens if you use a constant URL instead? Try `"http://www.microsoft.com"` instead.